# How to disable link in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and there is a simple bugs that i can't fix, I know it was simple question but I appreciate those entertain me on how to do this. How can I disable a link in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another simple solution to this is to use the `ng-href` attribute, which is just like the `href` one, but the value is dynamic. Angular allows expressions, so you can use the tertiary ? : construct to select whether or not to include a URL/value. So something like:

```
<a ng-href="{{condition ? 'http://...' : ''}}">My link</a>
```

There is a down-side to this, because the `href` is being played with dynamically, you don't get the CSS rendering the same as a traditional `href`ed link.

This isn't really disabling a link so much as dynamically choosing whether or not to set the `href` attribute, so for full functionality, writing a directive might be better. It really is worth getting the hang of writing attributes in the long run, but this might be a good temporary fix.